# Issue with Roundcube on Postfix, Dovecot, MySQL

Tags: mysql, dovecot, roundcube

I am seasoned with Ubuntu, Apache and MySQL but new to the email server world and an looking for some troubleshooting tips with my server configuration. 
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL as instructed in this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin
with the exception of spamassassin.
I then installed postfixadmin to provide a graphical means of configuring my virtual postfix users/domains. 
Thereafter I installed Roundcube as instructed in this tutorial: http://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-roundcube-webmail-ubuntu/ with the exception of the version (I am using 1.1.4). Everything checks out; I can Telnet into my mail server with accounts created using postfixadmin and can verify the mailbox(es) exists. The server receives email from external domains and can send as well. However, when I attempt to login to a verified user account via-Roundcube it fails. I have tried and tried again to find what is missing and have hit a wall. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Best Regards, 
-Joe

Comment: This has got nothing to do with sw development. Consider migrating this question to the serverfault site within stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, I would double check that RC is configured correctly to communicate with dovecot: this is the piece of software that is going to handle the authentication. To verify the software settings, one could switch on the debugging of both RC and dovecot.

Check RC configuration files to make sure that it is set up to connect to the right server and port. These settings can be found  either in 'config.inc.php' or in 'defaults.inc.php' under the 'config' directory of RC. Look for IMAP section and the following strings:

```
$config['default_host'] = 'tls://localhost';
$config['default_port'] = 143;
$config['imap_auth_type'] = null;
```

Pay special attention to the 'tls://' ('ssl://') prefixes -- these control the usage of encryption during negotiation with IMAP server (tls issues STARTTLS command while connecting on a standard port, and ssl expects connection to be encrypted from the very start and thus is generally used to connect to a dedicated 'encryped' port): for the purposes of debugging one might want to disable encryption altogether. I would propose to use the same hostname and port as were used for telnetting.

If these settings seem to be right, one can proceed to debugging of IMAP connection from RC to dovecot. To enable debugging, edit defaults.inc.php once again:

```
$config['debug_level'] = 1;
$config['log_driver'] = 'syslog';
$config['syslog_id'] = 'roundcube';
$config['syslog_facility'] = LOG_MAIL;
$config['log_logins'] = true;
$config['imap_debug'] = true;
```

This would direct debug information of RC IMAP negotiation with dovecot to /var/log/mail.log, where you most probably would be able to identify the problem.